# NoReverseMatch at /answer/ Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['answer/$(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']

Tags: python, django

for some reason I cannot seem to solve this bug. , any help will be appreciated

this is the 
**models.py**

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    # return f"/question/{self.slug}"
    return reverse('qna:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**qna/Urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', AnsListView.as_view(),name='list'),
url(r'^create$', AnsCreateView.as_view(),name='create'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', AnsDetailView.as_view(),name='detail'),
```

**main/url.py**

```
url(r'^answer/$',include('qna.urls', namespace='qna')),
```

**Error** when try to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/answer/

```
NoReverseMatch at /answer/
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['answer/$(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/answer/
Django Version: 1.11.2
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'detail' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['answer/$(?P<pk>\\d+)/$']
Exception Location: C:\Users\prash\Desktop\prashantks\pksproject\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're including the urls from answer, you need to remove the `$` sign, this indicates the end of a regex..

```
url(r'^answer/$',include('qna.urls', namespace='qna')),
             /\
```

should be

```
url(r'^answer/',include('qna.urls', namespace='qna')),
```